# Canadian Taxes for Buying Bitcoins

Tags: trading, taxes, canada

I saw this [post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/535/tax-implications-in-canada-of-buying-and-selling-bitcoins), but it really didn't help me.

How should I fill out my tax forms if I am only buying and holding bitcoins, not selling them?

This [page](http://www.canadiantaxlitigation.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/2013-0514701I7.txt) appears to suggest that I only need to worry about taxes if I profit off of them when I sell them:

```
Buying and Selling Bitcoins

Income Tax Implications

Where a person trades or sells Bitcoins like a commodity (i.e., speculating
on the changes in the value of Bitcoins), the resulting gain or loss may be 
on account of income or capital.  Determining whether such a transaction is
on account of income or capital can only be made following an assessment of 
all the facts relating to the particular taxpayer’s circumstances.
Paragraphs 9 to 32 of Interpretation Bulletin IT-479R, “Transactions in 
securities”, provide general comments for purposes of determining whether 
transactions are income or capital in nature.

The determination of the income tax consequences relating to the treatment 
of gains and losses arising from the purchase and sale of Bitcoins would be 
generally the same as for transaction[enter link description here][3]s 
involving other types of commodities.

Example:

Mr. X bought a Bitcoin on June 1, 2013 for $100.  Mr. X then sold the 
Bitcoin on December 1, 2013 for $500.

Based on his particular facts and circumstances, Mr. X determined that the 
gain was on account of capital.

Mr. X has a capital gain since he sold a capital property for more than the 
total of its adjusted cost base and the outlays and expenses incurred to 
sell the property.

Mr. X’s capital gain is $400 ($500 less $100).  Mr. X will need to report 
$200 as a taxable capital gain (only 1/2 of the capital gain is taxable) on 
his 2013 Income Tax and Benefit Return.
```

Although I don't know how reputable that page is, so here is the [official, incomprehensible source](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/tp/it479r/README.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. You have no taxes and no need to report them if you have not sold/spent any of the coins in the tax year.

You do need to keep records of your purchases, because when you do come to sell, you'll need to work out the potential gains you've made.

If you do need to work out your gains, you can use https://bitcoin.tax or other capital gains calculators that can work out the total gains from all your selling or spending.